# Sub-Menu Options for Radio Button in Apex in Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I got 3 radio option values like All,Active,Test.

If we choose either Active or test,a sub-menu must be created under Active and Test radio options respectively. But, i'm failing to get the format. Its displaying the sub menu options in the top later radio options. Any work around to fix this?

```
<apex:outputPanel id="DetailList" >                        
      <apex:selectRadio value="{!AvailRecords}" >
          <apex:selectOption itemLabel="All" itemValue="All"></apex:selectOption>
          <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Active" itemValue="Active"></apex:selectOption>
          <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(AvailRecords == 'Active',true,false)}" >
            All Active Records
         </apex:outputPanel>                                 
          <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Test" itemValue="Test"> </apex:selectOption>          
         <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(AvailRecords == 'Test',true,false)}">
            All Test Records
         </apex:outputPanel> 
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="EventsDetailList" status="loadingstatuscheck"  action="{!EveChnageSupport}" />  
</apex:selectRadio>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce doesn't allow to render outpanels between radios. In this particular case we can build our own html page with utilising javascript functionality.

Following example is placing outputpanel between radios, but hiding them. Javasript is looking for panels and updates its style accordingly to selected value:

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Account">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function togglePanels(value) {
        var panels = document.querySelectorAll('[id$="Toggle"]');
        for (var i = 0, length = panels.length; i < length; i++){    
            if (panels[i].id.indexOf(value) > -1){
                panels[i].style.display = 'inline';
            } else {
                panels[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
    </script>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:outputPanel id="DetailList" >
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="All" onclick="togglePanels(this.value); ">All</input><br/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="Active" onclick="togglePanels(this.value); ">Active</input><br/>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="true" id="ActiveToggle" style="display:none">
                    All Active Records
                    <br/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="Test" onclick="togglePanels(this.value); ">Test</input><br/>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="true" id="TestToggle" style="display:none">
                    All Test Records
                <br/>
                </apex:outputPanel>         
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for ur code Ilya. But, i need the radio options and its sub menu in Vertical format. Thanks Again.

Comment: @Rv1, you can specify direction by adding layout to selectRadio

Comment: As per my requirement, 'All Active Records' should get displayed under Active Radio Option. is that possible.

Comment: @Rv1, please find updated answer.